Are the definitions of very ample invertible sheaf between Vakil and Stacks project equivalent?
$\newcommand{\ra}{\rightarrow}$
Vakil's Foundations of Algebraic Geometry, definition 17.2.2 : Let $f : X \ra Y$ be proper, and $L$ is an invertible sheaf on $X$. Then, $L$ is very ample if there is an isomorphism $X \simeq \underline{Proj}_Y(F)$ (isomorphism commutes with the morphism to $Y$), for some graded quasicoherent sheaf of algebras $F$ on $Y$, such that $F_0 = O_Y$, $F_1$ is finite type, and $F$ is generated in degree 1, and under this isomorphism, $L = O(1)$.
Stacks Project Definition 29.38.1 : Let $f : X \ra S$ be a morphism of schemes. Let $L$ be an invertible sheaf on $X$. Then,  $L$ is very ample if there is a quasicoherent sheaf $E$ on $S$ and an immersion $i : X \ra \mathbb{P}_S(E)$ such that $L = i^* O(1)$.
Are these two definitions equivalent in the case that the morphism is proper? Unlike Vakil, the definition in the Stacks Project doesn't have any finiteness condition on $E$ , and the immersion is not required to be closed. There is lemma 29.39.1, but that lemma has an affine condition that I don't know how to get rid of.
